# Need a way to make my slider images have a fadeOut effect when clicking prev or next

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I need a way (js preferable) to make my slider images have the effect of fadeOut when I click the previous or next button.

I want the images in the slider to fade away when I click prev so that the next image can show...and same thing for when I click next, image slowly disappears and next slide image appears.

```
<ul class="slider">
             <li><img src="images/1.png" alt="img" width="979" height="470"></li>
             <li><img src="images/2.png" alt="img" width="979" height="470"></li>
             <li><img src="images/3.png" alt="img" width="979" height="470"></li>

</ul>
```

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript function as a great fade effect:

```
function fade(element) {
    var op = 1;  // initial opacity
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (op <= 0.1){
            clearInterval(timer);
            element.style.display = 'none';
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
        op -= op * 0.1;
    }, 50);
}
```

Here is an example implementation I wrote to fade through images:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
function fadeout(element) {
    var op = 1; // initial opacity
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (op <= 0.1) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            element.style.display = 'none';
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
        op -= op * 0.1;
    }, 50);
    }

    function fadein(element) {
    var op = 0.1; // initial opacity
    var intimer = setInterval(function () {
        if (op >= 1) {
            clearInterval(intimer);
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
        if (op == 0.1) {
            element.style.display = 'block';
        }
        op += op * 0.1;
    }, 50);
    }
    var images = [];
    var counter = 0;
    var state = 0;

    function initimages() {
    images[0] = document.getElementById("img1");
    images[1] = document.getElementById("img2");
    images[2] = document.getElementById("img3");
    for (i = 1; i < images.length; i++) {
        images[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    }

    function previous() {
    if (state == 0) {
        state = 1;
        fadeout(images[counter]);
        counter -= 1;
        if (counter < 0) {
            counter = images.length - 1;
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            fadein(images[counter]);
        }, 1300);
        setTimeout(function () {
            state = 0;
        }, 2500);
    }
    }

    function next() {
    if (state == 0) {
        state = 1;
        fadeout(images[counter]);
        counter += 1;
        if (counter >= images.length) {
            counter = 0;
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            fadein(images[counter]);
        }, 1300);
        setTimeout(function () {
            state = 0;
        }, 2500);
    }
    }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
div.imgcontainer {
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    padding:50px 0px;
    }
    div.imgcontainer img {
    background-color:#FFF;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    }
    </style>

    <title></title>
</head>

<body onload="initimages();">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
        <center>
            <img alt="1" id="img1" name="img1" src="">
            <img alt="2" id="img2" name="img2" src="">
            <img alt="3" id="img3" name="img3" src="">
        </center>
    </div>
        <input onclick="previous();" type="button" value="Previous">
        <input onclick="next();" type="button" value="Next">
</body>
</html>
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for what a very easy to use plugin by a guy called Malsup created. Check it out:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

You an set various effects for the slideshow including fade